# Find the most relevant records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

There are two tables:
Project and User
There are list of services in project and user.
Display the Most Relevant (Ones with the most match for services in the project and services offered by the user)

Have to write SQL Query for the following scenerio

**Project**

```
|         ProjectName        |    Services               |
|----------------------------|---------------------------|
|          Project X         |   "["a", "b", "c", "d"]"  |
|          Project Y         |   "["a", "e"]"            |
|          Project Z         |   "["a", "c", "d"]"       |
```

**User**

```
|         UserName        |    Services            |
|-------------------------|------------------------|
|          User A         |   "["a", "b", "c"]"    |
```

Now find and sort the projects with most number of services matched with user A.

**Result**

```
|         ProjectName        |    Services              |
|----------------------------|--------------------------|
|          Project X         |  "["a", "b", "c", "d"]"  |
|          Project Z         |  "["a", "c", "d"]"       |
|          Project Y         |  "["a", "e"]"            |
```

**Explanation**

Project X matches with all the 3 services of user ("a", "b", "c")
Project Z matches with 2 services of user ("a", "c")
Project Y matches with 1 services of user ("a")

Comment: Storing data as lists will cause you lots of problems.

Comment: Parse user's list to separate values, join, aggregate and calculate the amount, sort by it.